# Issue with sql query to get the results

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am having a problem with a sql query. This is how the table structure looks like.

[image]

The scenario is there are order details in order table(Initially shipping details id is null) and ordered items are also saved accordingly. When dispatching the orders the driver can select one or more orders. Assume if he selects two orders('CC0-C1B-50B-63B' and 'FB2-FC6-57B-DD8') a new record is added to the shipping_details table(so the no of places is 2 in our case) and two records are saved accordingly in Delivery_Place table.

What I want : If I select order No 'CC0-C1B-50B-63B', I want to get all the delivery orders(In our case there is another order which is 'FB2-FC6-57B-DD8'and the result should be those 2 orders) and the departmentID in orderd_items table for those 2 orders. (If there are multiple items in a single order, all items are in a same department)

So I tried this query,

```
select  oi.FKOrderID,dp.deliveryPlaceID,dp.FKShippingDetailsID,dp.city,dp.position,oi.FKDepartmentID
  from 
 `order` o join `shipping_details` sd 
  on o.FKShippingDetailsID = sd.shippingDetailsID  
  join `ordered_items` oi 
  on o.orderID = oi.FKOrderID 
  join `delivery_places` dp 
  on dp.FKShippingDetailsID=sd.shippingDetailsID 
  where o.orderID = 'CC0-C1B-50B-63B'  
  group by dp.deliveryPlaceID
  order by dp.position asc ;
```

And the result is this,

[image]

But I for second row I should get 'FB2-FC6-57B-DD8' as FKOrderID and '11' for the FKDepartmentID.

This is the data table

[image]

**UPDATED WITH INPUT DATA**

Order Table

[image]

Shipping Details Table

[image]

Ordered_items table (columns:   orderedItemsID ,    FKItemID ,  quantity ,  size,   FKDepartmentID ,    FKOrderID)

[image]

Department Table

[image]

So how to modify this query to get that result?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry would you mind creating a simple version  of your issue....having a hard time trying to pin exactly what you want

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I've always found ER-diagrams hard to read. Posting a picture of a whiteboard just makes it worse.

Comment: If I select order No 'CC0-C1B-50B-63B', I want to get all the delivery orders(In our  .......stop ...explain this I want to get all the delivery orders of what im confused to which?

Comment: @careen just start to read from query. sorry for the complexity

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY dp.deliveryPlaceID` when you don't have any aggregation functions?

Comment: @Barmar I want the deliverylocation details separately.

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help until we see some input data.

Comment: ok I will add some pics , wait

Comment: give me the table column headers for the results with the red box on it

Comment: @careen wait 1 min , ill post them

Comment: lol im reading......

Comment: i think you need to add a && statment here so " where o.orderID = 'CC0-C1B-50B-63B' &&  ??

Comment: are you wanting the result with 11 aswell, or not? if yes you will need to have two values to compare that are the same like if id ==3  && / or somethingelse == whatever

Comment: @Careen yes I need the data like in the ordered_items image. But instead of I m getting 12 for FKDepartmentID  for FKOrderID 'FB2-FC6-57B-DD8'. Can you explain more or edit my query as you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved the result ,

```
select 
distinct(oi.FKOrderID),dp.deliveryPlaceID,dp.FKShippingDetailsID,dp.city,dp.longitude,dp.latitude,dp.timestamp,dp.position,dp.status,o.orderStatus,oi.FKDepartmentID
from 
`ordered_items` oi,
`order` o join `shipping_details` sd 
on o.FKShippingDetailsID = sd.shippingDetailsID  
join `delivery_places` dp 
on dp.FKShippingDetailsID=sd.shippingDetailsID  
where o.orderID = 'CC0-C1B-50B-63B'  
and
oi.FKOrderID in (select orderID from `order` where    
FKShippingDetailsID=o.FKShippingDetailsID)
group by oi.FKOrderID
order by dp.position asc
```

And here is the result,

[image]